# Winrt WebView security level - Not possible to load external files

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have scenario in which I would like to download zip with some html, js, css, pictures, fonts and show them in the WebView in my winrt (C#/XAML) application. But I deal with huge problem. **IE (and WebView too) can't access files from Local folder of my application (LocalState folder)**. It is possible to turn off security [restrictions in IE](http://oi61.tinypic.com/63vq7b.jpg) and after this I can open downloaded index.html with all styles and resources.

Problem is, that **WebView behaves like IE** and I can't show this page from **Local folder**. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8d2a70ba-796e-46ca-8be8-02acb2934ec8/change-security-level-of-webview-control) is some forum page with this problem but it does not solve it too.

Another forum answer says that I should save data to **Installation folder** of my app, but I really don't like this solution. In my opinion, there can be some problems with access rights etc. too.

Can you please advice me how to solve this problem?
Thank you.